# Overwrite auto_now for unittest

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I've defined some timestamps for events in the database as `auto_now_add`, as the information should be stored with it's timestamp the same time the event is stored.

The description of the events is something like

```
class NewEvent(models.Model):
    '''
    Individual event
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.FloatField(null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

To test the module, I'm generating some information in the database in the `test.py` file, this way:

```
    for event in EVENT_TYPES:
        time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        for i in range(48):
            time = time.replace(hour=i / 2)
            NewEvent(name=event,
                     timestamp=time,
                     quantity=i).save()
```

I must generate events with its timestamp of yesterday (the module will then summarize them). The problem is that you can't overwrite the timestamp. The timestamp it's the one when the event it's produced, the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) states that very clearly.

So, how to generate data with appropiate timestamps for the testing? I've had several ideas:

- Maybe generate the database data in a different way, outside the Model classes. Where and how?
- Somehow define a different class or change the class to behave differently during test, something like

_

```
 if testing:
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 else:
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
```

Or maybe there's an even easier way to do this... Any ideas?

Comment: How about `timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=testing)` as a simplification?

Comment: `testing` variable will be True if testing? That will be great, but in this case, it should be something like `auto_now_add=not testing`, I think...

Comment: It's your question and your example, feel free to fix it.

Comment: for a dynamic option see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to create data overriding the default values using a fixture.

I've created a `test_data.json` file with the data in the following format:

```
[
{
    "model": "stats_agg.newevent",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "event1",
        "quantity":0.0,
        "timestamp": "2010-02-15 00:27:40"
     }
},
{
    "model": "stats_agg.newevent",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "name": "event1",
        "quantity":1.0,
        "timestamp": "2010-02-15 00:27:40"
     }
},
...
```

and then add to the test unit

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):
   fixtures = ['test_data.json']
```

Comment: Fixtures do not rule, they have serious problem. Use [Factories](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orms.html)

Answer (score 7):

Another way of handling this is to use a [QuerySet `update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) after the instance is created which may be more useful depending upon your use case.

As an `update` call is performed at the SQL level it will skip validation, signals and and custom save functionality. It will require a secondary database call which can impact performance so it should be used with consideration.

```
for event in EVENT_TYPES:
    time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    for i in range(48):
        time = time.replace(hour=i / 2)
        instance = NewEvent(name=event, quantity=i).save()
        NewEvent.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(timestamp=time)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with fixtures for me, is that I need to test that certain records that are older than 30 days are not returned, and ones that are not 30 days old are returned ... using static fixtures this cannot be done (in a lazy way). So what I chose to do is mock the timezone.now function which django uses to get the datetime to use.

```
from django.utils import timezone 

class SomeTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_auto_add(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        now_31 = now - datetime.timedelta(days=31)
        self.mock('timezone.now', returns=now_31, tracker=None)
        SomeObject.objects.create() # has auto_now_add field ...
```

for mocking I use [minimocktest](http://pykler.github.io/MiniMockTest/)

Comment: faking datetime is much better option: http://tech.yunojuno.com/mocking-dates-with-django