# Mock timing in a context to create models with a field DateTimeField with auto_now_add=True

Tags: python, django, testing, mocking, timing

I'd like to mock timing so that be able to *set* certain time to a field of type `DateTimeField` with `auto_now_add=True` during my tests e.g:

```
class MyModel:
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...


class TestMyModel(TestCase):
    ...
    def test_something(self):
        # mock current time so that `created_at` be something like 1800-02-09T020000
        my_obj = MyModel.objects.create(<whatever>)
        # and here my_obj.created_at == 1800-02-09T000000
```

I'm aware the current date is [**always**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/) used for this type of fields, that is why I'm looking for an alternative to mock somehow the system timing, but **just in a context**.

I've tried some approaches, for instance, creating a context with `freeze_time` but didn't work:

```
with freeze_now("1800-02-09"):
    MyModel.objects.create(<whatever>)
    # here the created_at doesn't fit 1800-02-09
```

Ofc I guess, this is due to the machinery behind the scene to create the object when `auto_now_add=True`.

I don't want to remove `auto_now_add=True` and/or use default values.

Is there a way we can mock the timing so that we can make this type of field to get the time that I want in certain context?

I'm using `Django 1.9.6` and `Python 3.4`

Comment: Django and Python versions?

Comment: You could probably mock the pre_save method on the datetime field - a little icky but hey, time right?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.9.6 and Python 3.4

Comment: this might be useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273463/overwrite-auto-now-for-unittest?lq=1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution, it is based on [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock):

```
def mock_now():
    return <mock time>

class TestMyModel(TestCase):
    ...
    @mock.patch('django.utils.timezone.now', mock_now)
    def test_as_decorator(self):
        ...
        my_obj = MyModel.objects.create(<whatever>)
        ...
         # here the created_at field has the mocked time :)

    def test_as_context_manager(self):
         mocked_dt = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 3, 11, 15, 0)
         with mock.patch('django.utils.timezone.now', mock.Mock(return_value=mocked_dt)):
             my_obj = MyModel.objects.create(<whatever>)
             # here the created_at field has the mocking time :)
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @trinchets answer, here it is as context manager,

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from mock import patch, Mock


last_week = timezone.now() - timedelta(weeks=1)
with patch('django.utils.timezone.now', Mock(return_value=last_week)):
    # Make your models/factories

# Carry on with normal time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.test import TestCase
from mock import patch


class TestMyModel(TestCase):
    @patch('django.utils.timezone.now', )
    def test_something(self, mock_now):
        mock_now.return_value = datetime(2015, 9, 3, 11, 15, 0)
```