# Django mock timezone aware datetime on creating model

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a test where I create a few objects:

```
def test_get_courier_task_returns_couriers_tasks(self):
    with patch('django.utils.timezone.now', return_value=make_aware(datetime(2018, 1, 24, 11, 57))):
        task1 = TaskFactory()

        response = json.loads(MyAPI.get_tasks_list(self.user.username))
        print('[*] Response timestamp: {}'.format(response['content'][0]['timestamp']))
```

The `Task` has `created_timestamp` field with `auto_add_now` set to True and `to_json()` method which is used in `get_tasks_list()` above:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def to_json(self):
        to_return = {
            'timestamp': self.created_timestamp.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
        }
        return to_return
```

Unfortunately tests give this output:

> [*] Response timestamp: 24-01-2018 10:57

I have checked that this is timezone aware, but instead of giving me UTC+1 it gives UTC+0 on saving. What do I have to do? I have `USE_TZ = True` in my settings and I have applied migrations. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284183/mock-timing-in-a-context-to-create-models-with-a-field-datetimefield-with-auto-n) did not help with my problem.

Comment: There is no better answer than in question you mentioned. Double check if you're using new=Mock(return_value=...) in patch() arguments, not return_value=Mock(...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out that giving timezone explicityl helped:

```
with patch('django.utils.timezone.now', return_value=datetime(2018, 1, 24, 11, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('utc'))):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing [`make_aware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware) with the timezone you want.

Also checking for a specific time in the test is a bit circular, probably don't need to check for it and just make sure it runs and produces a timestamp.

Comment: I use `make_aware`, but maybe checking that timestamps match will be enough. All in all if they match in one timezone, they will in any other.